# How to remove "new window from here" menu item (MMC 3.0)

Tags: menu, contextmenu, mmc3

Currently I'm developing an MMC 3.0 based application. How I'm able to hide\remove the menu item "New window from here" which appears when you right click on any node in the left=hand pane (this is implemented to the Microsoft Event Viewer)?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Right click on the msc file and then click Author.
There go to File > Options. In the combo box select: "User mode - limited access, single window"
close the console and save the changes.
Run the MSC file and now the "New window from here" won't be there any more.

dig.